# Extract thumbnail from an image using Gimp

Tags: image, exif, gimp

How can I extract the thumbnail from an image using Gimp?

I know Gimp can properly read the EXIF information inside a file. I want it to extract the Thumbnail embedded in the EXIF and save as a different file.

I am not looking at scaling to make a thumbnail.

Answer (score 0):

You should add more information, about what you are exactly trying.
Do you try to get an thumbnail from an image, were this thumbnail is part of the metadata or do you want to asses the thumbnail Gimp creates for the file dialogs? Or do you want just an small version of an image?

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.